# keyIsPressed to write on canvas where mouse is clicked p5js

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I am working on a function which enables users to write onto screen where mouse has been clicked however there are a few problems.

Firstly: keyIsPressed is executed multiple times making each key appear more than once with a single click.

Secondly: It will only allow for a single letter to be printed before the mouseX and mouseY are set back to -1.

Here is my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  var startMouseX = -1;
  var startMouseY = -1;
  var drawing = false;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  if(mouseIsPressed)
    {
       startMouseX = mouseX;
       startMouseY = mouseY;

       drawing = true;
    }
    else if(keyIsPressed)
        {
            textSize(20);
            text(key,startMouseX,startMouseY);
            startMouseX += textWidth(key);            
        }
    else{
        drawing = false;
        startMouseX = -1;
        startMouseY = -1;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach with the 'drawing' variable works.
But instead of drawing the new letter in draw you can use the  keyTyped() function. In the same manner you could use mouseMoved() to reset the 'drawing' variable

```
var drawing = true;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function keyTyped() {
    if (drawing) text(key, mouseX, mouseY);
    drawing = false;
}

function mouseMoved() {
    drawing = true;
  }
```

Comment: If you need a more elaborate solution you should create a class for the letters and create an instance in 'keyTyped()'. This letters can then be drawn each frame.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
let drawing = false;
let drawMouseX = -1;
let drawMouseY = -1;


function setup() {
  
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  background("white");
  
}

function keyTyped(){
  
  if(!drawing){
  
    drawing = true;
    
    drawMouseX = mouseX;
    drawMouseY = mouseY;
  
  }
  
  text(key, drawMouseX, drawMouseY)
    
  drawMouseX += textWidth(key);
  
}

function mouseMoved(){
  
  drawing = false;
  
}
```

This makes it so the things you type are permanently on the canvas. Is this what you wanted? if not, it would be a lot harder.